"could live" vs "could have lived"

He could have lived there for two years

This sentence is correct it means that it was possible that he lived there in the past but we can't be sure if it really happened. What if I change it a little?

In the past he could live there for two years

Does the meaning stay the same or there is something different?

Why do you ask? Where did these sentences come from? What is it that you’re trying to learn? What research have you done? What did it uncover for you? Why was it inadequate to your purposes?

I just want to know as much as possible. Saw somewhere both of them and now I want to compare the meaning

That's it. Mnnn

No, the revised sentence is off. It doesn't read well, its meaning is unclear, and it tries to explain that the past tense is 'in the past'.

The sentences have quite different meanings. 1) It's possible that he lived there for two years, although it's unclear whether 'could' refers to the location, the time span, or both. 2) There was a place he lived where he was allowed to stay two years at a time (but perhaps now there is no restriction).

@WeatherVane  thank you. Would it make any difference if we changed "could" to "might" in both examples?

@WeatherVane: That's only one possible interpretation of #1. Another is that the option was available to him, even though it's a matter of historical fact that he didn't live there for two years. There may be other interpretations for both utterances in specific contexts (possibly "contrived"). Don't waste your time getting bogged down with the implications of replacing could by might.

Do you understand the difference between (1) "We could live there" and (2) "We can live there"?


He can live there for two years. ✅

This means the person has either the possibility, the permission or the ability to live in a certain habitation or a particular area.

He could live there for two years. ✅

This is not the past equivalent of the previous sentence. The meaning still refers to the present. In this instance "could" suggests a slightly more remote possibility or ability to live somewhere.

In the past he could live there for two years. ❌

Even though the majority of native speakers will probably guess its meaning, the sentence is ambiguous. Did the person actually live in that place for two years? Did they have permission (perhaps a clause written in a contract) to live there for only two years? Did they have the physical mobility to live there but today they are no longer able to?

[In the past] he could have lived there for two years. ✅

In 2020 he had the opportunity of living in the Upper East Side of New York. ✅

In 2020 he had the possibility of living rent-free for two years. ✅

In 2020 he could live rent-free for two years. ✅

In 2020 he was able to live rent-free for two years. ✅


When we speak about ability in the past, the modal "could" is sometimes used.

My 87-year-old aunt can still drive. ✅ (present)
My 87-year-old aunt could drive to the city centre but she prefers to ride on a bus. ✅ (present)
My 87-year-old aunt could drive when she was 18. ✅ (past)
My 87-year-old aunt learnt how to drive when she was 18. ✅ (past)


No, I think this would give the sentence a slightly different meaning. 'Could have' in this context likely means that the subject of the sentence had the resources or opportunity to do so.
So if someone is living alone in a cabin way out in the woods you might say 'They could live there for 2 years with the giant store of food they have stocked away.' But then perhaps this person realizes there is a leak in their water tank. They might complain to themselves 'If not for that faulty tank I could have lived there for two years.'
Lastly, suppose this person moves into a village and makes a few friends. They return to the little cabin in the woods which they still own and find that they get lonely. They might say ‘In the past I could have lived here for 2 years; but now I start to go a little crazy after being alone for a week or two.’
As far as the subject 'not being sure' that isn't what it most likely implies. Even if we imagine the man has amnesia and is trying to decide whether he lived in a place for two years the implication has more to do with ability rather than whether it happened or not. If the person looked around and saw food and a place to sleep he might say 'I could have lived here for two years.' By this he means that it seems possible based seeing some of the things he would need to have lived there for so long.
Ultimately, it's hard to say for sure without more context about where the sentence is coming from. If you wanted to make it clear that it was possible someone lived somewhere for 2 years I would suggest:

"It is possible this is where he lived for those two years; there's no way to tell."

"Perhaps this is where he was living for those two years."

"Maybe this is where he was living for those two years no one seemed to be able to find him."


The key words that emphasize the uncertainty are: "maybe, possibly, perhaps."
Whereas 'could have' usually implies an ability for something to have happened in the past.
